# 403 Access Forbidden when directly accessing a page using base_url()

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, xmlhttprequest

I'm getting a 403 error when trying to access a page via `XHR` :

```
$("form").submit(function( event ) {
  xmlhttp.open("GET","<?=base_url('application/views/pages/search_sql.php'); ?>",true);
  xmlhttp.send();

  event.preventDefault();
});
```

I could load the page `search_sql.php` by straightforward `xmlhttp.open("GET","search_sql",true);` but then it doesn't load the script directly - instead it is handled by controller and loaded with other views which are unwanted in this case.

Comment: try to access a controller method which load your view page

Comment: good idea, but `xmlhttp.open("GET"," <?php $this->load->view('pages/search_sql.php'); ?> ",true);` loads the view along with other, unwanted views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using CodeIgniter so why are you trying to load anything directly?

Call the page as you would normally and add a controller method to do what is required in this situation. So:

Assuming you have a controller called 'Search' create a method called something relevant lets say 'special_case' and call that with any parameters it requires like so

```
<?php

class Search extends Controller {

    function index()
    {
        // I assume this is what it is currently doing
    }

    function special_case()
    {
        // Make this do whatever is required in this case.
    }
```

Then call it from your Javascript using the standard CodeIgniter controller/method/param1/param2 ...... mechanism.

Comment: yeah, I've made it by creating a new controller `scripts`, adding `$route['scripts/(:any)'] = 'scripts/script/$1';` to routes and load the view by `xmlhttp.open("GET","scripts/search_sql",true);`. thanks for ideas.